# jmeter - dashboard report - percentiles appear to be invalid

Tags: jmeter, percentile

[image: JMeter Dashboard - Response Time Percentiles]

I've run a jmeter test - 1 thread per second for 10 minutes (~600 requests in total). I generate a dashboard report from the generated *.jtl file. Reviewing the percentiles

1. I dont understand how/why the 99th percentile (green) can be higher than the max (yellow)?
2. I can see the max times correlate with the times in the *.jtl file so am happy they are valid numbers.
3. I CANNOT see the 99th percentile times correlate with the times in the *.jtl file. (I *thought* the value had to be a real number in teh dataset) - where does it come from?

Can I get some help/suggestions/input on my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume for simplicity there is 1 request per minute,

In your graph the first request took 2.5 seconds in first minute

And all other requests took 0.5 seconds

Your Max is returning the Max per minute which is `2.5`, `0.5`, `0.5` , ...

You 99 percentile is showing average time from the start of the test reducing lowest value:

- 2.5 + 0.5 -> remove lowest 0.5 and returns `2.5`
- 2.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 -> remove lowest 0.5 and returns 3/2 - > `1.5`
- 2.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 -> remove lowest 0.5 and return 3.5/3 - > `~ 1`

As you can see 99 percentile is correct and have higher value than Max which have a peak at start.

jtl is a result file per response, it doesn't hold averages as percentile.